Subdomains from NPM dont work via Dynv6-Main-Zone
Today I got a new Router.
Unfortunately I only get DS-lite from now on.
Extra DS does cost a lot extra for private usage.
I have 3 Webserver publically reachable: Jellyfin, Nextcloud and Home Assistant.
All of them get connected via NPM.
As DuckDNS doesnt work with IPv6, I tried to switch to DynV6.
I created a zone and I am able to update the IPv6 as well as the correct AAAA entry.
I can reach NPM with exactly that zone-name "xxx.dynv6.net". If I open that site I get reconnected according to "Default Site" (What to show when Nginx is hit with an unknown Host ). That is as expected, because I only use subdomains.
The configured subdomains to that zone in NPM, wont work: jf.xxx.dynv6.net; nc.xxx.dynv6.net and ha.xxx.dynv6.net
If I open [::(Ipv6 from Jellyfin)]:8096 then it works.
I am not going to bother with SSL until this works.
Can anyone help me? I already bothered Copilot to death :D

I changed the DynDNS-Server.
I changed to https://ipv64.net/.
And it is just working!
I only submit my IPv6 via Script and incoming IPv4 is getting blocked, so Old browsers and some small scale open source projects wont be able to connect to my Server at all (I just have to keep that in mind).
Nginx Proxy Manger doesnt need to be configured specifically.
The script to update the IP needs to be run on the server where NPM is installed (obviously).
If you have local IPv4-Network, you can use that in NPM.
In NPM I only used local IPv4 to refer all incoming IPv6-requests to.
If you see this post and think about changing to IPv64.net, be aware, that it is a german only website
